# How do I insert variable values into DOM style value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code: When the slide value changes the transform property for the element should take the slide value which by default are 0deg, i want it to change gradually for the slide value, but i don't know why but it's not working as it should.

```
<pre>
<body>
<div id="trsScript">
</div>
<input type="range" min="0" max="360" id="mxConcept" oninput="shthis()"             
onchange="shthis()"></BR>
<p id="callme"></p>
<style>
#trsScript{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

</style>

<script>
function shthis(){
    var x = document.getElementById('mxConcept').value;
        document.getElementById('callme').innerHTML=x;
        document.getElementById("trsScript").style.webkitTransform =         
"rotate(100deg)";
}


</script>
</body>
</pre>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqMXpX)

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't help people who are trying to answer your question much. Instead describe what is currently happening and what you expect to happen so we can understand what you are trying to accomplish and what might be going wrong. Reading [ask] will help you get more/better quality answers in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You must apply the value x to the transform property like this:

```
 function shthis(){
        var x = document.getElementById('mxConcept').value;
            document.getElementById('callme').innerHTML=x;
            document.getElementById("trsScript").style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+x+"deg)";
    }
```

**update:**

```
document.getElementById("trsScript").style.webkitTransform = `rotate(${x}deg)`
```

also works using [template literals.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: This isn't a 'must' anymore with template literals. `.webkitTransform = \`rotate(${x}deg)\`;`